# How can I plot many vectors in the same graph using a loop 'for', matlab

Tags: matlab

How I can show in only one figure, several pairs of points x, y ?
I've tried everything that I found on google, but in all cases only a single ordered pair of points x,y is shown.

Thank you.

```
pws = 2000;
q0EF = 500;
EF_vec = [0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9];
hold all;
for k=1:length(EF_vec)
    if(EF_vec(k) <= 1)
        i = 1;
        clearvars y x;
        for pwfi=0:100:pws
            pwfp = pws - (pws - pwfi )*EF_vec(k);
            y(i) = pwfp;
            x(i) = q0EF * (1 - 0.2*(pwfp/pws) - 0.8*(pwfp/pws)^2 );
            i = i + 1;
        end
        plot(x, y); % this doesnt work. This only show only the lastest x,y values
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `hold on` to append more values onto your `plot` with multiple `plot` calls.  I see you're using `hold all`, but that only works **when there is a figure open**.  You have no figure open initially, so you need to do that.  Therefore, spawn a new figure, use `hold on`, then use your code.  It's also a good idea to plot all of your points as singular points.  `plot` defaults to joining all of the points together by a straight line, so append a `'.'` as the third parameter to it:

```
pws = 2000;
q0EF = 500;
EF_vec = [0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9];
figure; %// Change
hold on;
for k=1:length(EF_vec)
    if(EF_vec(k) <= 1)
        i = 1;
        clearvars y x;
        for pwfi=0:100:pws
            pwfp = pws - (pws - pwfi )*EF_vec(k);
            y(i) = pwfp;
            x(i) = q0EF * (1 - 0.2*(pwfp/pws) - 0.8*(pwfp/pws)^2 );
            i = i + 1;
        end
        plot(x, y, '.'); %// Change
    end
end
```

Comment: No problem. Please consider accepting one of our answers. That's done by clicking on the checkmark icon underneath the up and down arrows at the top of any of our posts. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use plot(x, y, 'x'), which generates a scatter plot and use hold on to plot into the figure you should open before the for loops.

```
figure;
% looops
plot(x, y, 'x');
hold on
```

Your code works when I use it but you can't really see all curves as they are too close together. If you zoom in you can see them.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a cell array

```
pws = 2000;
q0EF = 500;
EF_vec = [0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9];

X = cell(size(EF_vec));
Y = cell(size(EF_vec));

for k=1:length(EF_vec)
    if(EF_vec(k) <= 1)
        i = 1;
        clearvars y x;
        for pwfi=0:100:pws
            pwfp = pws - (pws - pwfi )*EF_vec(k);
            y(i) = pwfp;
            x(i) = q0EF * (1 - 0.2*(pwfp/pws) - 0.8*(pwfp/pws)^2 );
            i = i + 1;
        end
        X{k} = x;
        Y{k} = y;
    end
end

X(cellfun(@isempty, X)) = [];
Y(cellfun(@isempty, Y)) = [];

plot(X{:}, Y{:});
```